# Combination of cross-correlation and t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, image-processing, cross-correlation

I have a coarse and noisy image data taken from two different but geometrically similar samples (pixel size are all the same). I want to prove that there is a statistically significant differences between the images from the two samples.

What I am thinking is calculating cross-correlation, and conducting t-test.
Cross-correlation between the images of the same sample should be higher than the correlation between the images of the different samples. There are about 30 images from each sample, so I can get 30C2 x 2 values from the correlation of the same sample and 30 x 30 values from the correlation of different sample. I wonder t-test is applicable to statistically prove the difference of those two groups of values.

Any comments & advice are greatly appreciated!

Comment: That depends. For example, if I were to take a picture of myself, and compare it to a picture of myself that is rotated 180 degrees, the two pictures would be statistically different pixel by pixel, but, in a larger sense, not different at all. I think one has to allow for what image differences are permissible and which are not, e.g., translations, rotations, flips, plastic deformations etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You can assume that there is no rotation, flips, translations etc.  The images has been taken in the exactly the same way. It is like one is "new sample" and the other is "degraded sample", and there is no other difference. But because of the noise in the image, even the images from the same sample look a little different. Do you think cross-correlation and t-test still works?

Comment: No, testing of that type is irrelevant to the hypothesis of unchanged information content. All information is context dependent. For example, suppose that an image is Gaussian smoothed, then comparison to the original should then be done AFTER deblurring of the smoothed image.

Comment: Sorry, I have some confusion.. My understanding so far is that the combination of cross correlation & t-test can work, but the samples may have some problems.. Is that correct? Do you mean there should not be a problem as long as I compare raw signals/images?

Comment: I also thought that even if the information is context-dependent, isn't it possible to analyse statistical difference under that specific context (as long as every image is under the same context)? I am sorry if it is a silly question. I am not good at statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a known noise environment, e.g., Gaussian, Poisson, the statistical significance for an imaging feature for noise reduction and image reconstruction can be set by the user, e.g., see the [Pixon method of image reconstruction](http://www.adass.org/adass/proceedings/adass98/puetterrc/). In other words, an image is noise and information, and let us call the latter the latent image. Next, if we wish to compare two images that only differ by noise content, and have the same latent image, then we know *a priori* that there is no significance of difference between those images, but there is a noise difference. Now, any test that we would perform that quantifies both noise in an image and the identical latent images, e.g. *t*-testing, would test for a detectable difference in the noise, not the images.

More generally, suppose we have two images and we wish to establish whether the latent images are the same, and discard the less than helpful noise. For example, to [compare a lakeside on a clear day, with the same lakeside barely visible in a fog](http://www.pixonimaging.com/px-40-series-demonstration-i.php), we would first apply image reconstruction, and then any rotations, translations, deformations, or contrast adjustments of those images to best superimpose them. Then, if the difference between the two adjusted images is only noise, and is without visible structure, then there is no significant structure to that difference. It helps to look at this rather than just talk about it, as follows.

[image]

Follow up answer: A Pixon would be a [paraboloid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid). That is the element that would be examined for tolerance of fit for the Pixon method. However, many Pixons would be included in a 2D map, and the agreement of fit is local, not global. It may be to compare images that you might settle for a less than ideal global procedure. For example, after noise reduction, rank all the pixel magnitudes in each image from least to greatest, and compare the distributions. That could be done using, for example, Spearman's rank correlation. That may avoid some of the image comparison problems like different image intensity, rotation and translation. One could even smooth both images (identically, and after noise reduction) to filter out additional noise for preventing false positive differences.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer. But I am afraid that it does not not answer my question. I got images from two different samples: 30 images from sample A and 30 images from sample B. Two samples generate **two different latent images**, but both are contaminated by noise. And I want to use t-test to prove there is a significant difference between the two samples A & B without a noise reduction measures. I am not trying to examine the difference between the images from the same samples (of course it just sees a noise).

Comment: T-test is conducted to distinguish two groups. One group has values obtained by cross-correlation of images between the sample A & B. The other group has values obtained by cross-correlation of images within the sample A (or B).

Comment: If two images are noise reduced so that the noise reduced latent images are available, then they can be compared. Using a *t*-test to do that would not be my first choice, [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) would be better.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can reduce the noise from my data. Mann-Whitney test seems more suitable than t-test. But can you apply that test to multi-dimensional data (2D image) ? The reason I was thinking about (normalised) cross-correlation is it can express the similarity of images with single value so that hypothesis testing can be easily followed. If you could give me information of how to test the differences of multidimensional data with Mann-Whitney test, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up answer. I will try using Spearman's rank correlation, and I will also try Mann-Whitney U test with cross-correlation. I have still difficulty to understand Pixon method. I may ask you a question in the future.